# java.io.EOFException:Did not receive <CRLF>.<CRLF> error when sending attachments greenmail test

Tags: testing, jakarta-mail, greenmail

I'm writing test for  my process mail app. I'm using greenmail for testing and everything works just fine when I send mime multipart message( html or text). But when I try to send a message with an attachment(because I need a message with attachment to test my methods for processing). I receive this error. Any idea why is this happening? Otherwise there is no problem with receiving and sending emails.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: Did not receive <CRLF>.<CRLF>
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.run(SmtpHandler.java:58)
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer$1.run(AbstractServer.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Did not receive <CRLF>.<CRLF>
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.mail.MovingMessage.readDotTerminatedContent(MovingMessage.java:107)
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.commands.DataCommand.execute(DataCommand.java:55)
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.handleCommand(SmtpHandler.java:97)
    at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.run(SmtpHandler.java:51)
    ... 2 more

and part of my code where I compose the message.

    List<String> attachList = new ArrayList<String>();
         attachList
         .add("/home/testattachments/attachment.txt");

    private  void createAttachPart(List<String> attachList,
            Multipart multipart) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        for (String path : attachList) {

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.attachFile(path);
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(new File(path).getName());
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimePart.ATTACHMENT);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The attempt to send the message is probably throwing an exception causing the connection to be closed.  Make sure you're catching all exceptions.  The exception is probably due to the attached file not being accessible.  Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and the debug output might give you more clues as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Its looking me a bug also check your all methods

Comment: You are right! The file was not accessible. I could now find out why it is not accessible because the path was correct.  I simply deleted the file and created a new one and now it works. The degubber is really helpful as well. Thank you!